# How to pass an extra parameter to 'get' in Rails 2.3 functional testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, get

Fellow Overflowers,

There is a peculiar issue I am dealing with and can find no obvious solution:

I am passing a parameter at the end of a url:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/patients/30/verify?unify=true
```

The parameter is not defined in my route which is defined like this:

```
verify_admin_patient GET /admin/patients/:id/verify(.:format) {:controller=>"admin/patients", :action=>"verify"}
```

What the controller does, it reads the `params[:unify]` and if it is true it verifies the details of a patient and adds them under the patient with the same name. If it is `false` it creates a new patient and adds the details.

However when it comes to testing is failing miserably and frustratingly:

```
test "should verify patient with unification" do
  get :verify, :id => patients(:one).to_param, :unify => "true"
  assert_equal "Successfully created patient.", @response.flash[:notice]
  assert_response :redirect
end
```

The reason is that the test is not actually passing the `unify` parameter to the controller and thus it fails.

I have tried different ways to send the parameter like `get '/admin/patients/30/verify?unify=true'` or adding more info to the request like `get '/admin/patients/30/verify?unify=true',:action => "verify", :controller => "admin/patients"` with absolutely no vain.

Has anybody a clue about how to pass this kind of parameter on the test?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to ask this - why on earth would you still use Rails 2.3?

Comment: Because you have a legacy app for example and an update is more work than a complete rewrite. And you don't have time or skills for both.

Answer (score 0):

```
 get :verify, :id => patients(:one).to_param, :unify => "true"
```

not

```
 get :verify, :id => patients(:one).to_param, :unify => true
```

Edit:

Head to your controller method, use

https://github.com/pry/pry

and put that as the first line of your method code. Run the tests, and it should pause there, indicating that you have indeed reached the point where the code is being run.

Then run the code in the method line by line, assuming you have no error and records are being created as expected, then the issue is with your test writing

Comment: Yes, have edited that as it it was reflected wrongly. However, there is no change in behavior. It is not passed at all.

Comment: Have you debugged something as Sherwyn Goh pointed out? It would also be helpful to see your failure output.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you have to pass all parameters for the params hash in the second parameter in the test, like for example:

```
test "should verify patient with unification" do
  get :verify, { :id => patients(:one).to_param, :unify => true }
  assert_equal "Successfully created patient.", @response.flash[:notice]
  assert_response :redirect
end
```

Does that work?